# How to factor $x_1^2+2 x_2^2-x_1 x_2-x_1$ to $x^TAx+c^Tx$ form

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd like to know how to factor $x_1^2+2 x_2^2-x_1 x_2-x_1$ to $x^TAx+c^Tx$ form. As a start, I understand that $x_1^2+2 x_2^2-x_1 x_2-x_1$ can be represented in matrix form as $[x_1, x_2]$(1, -1/2; -1/2, 2)$[x_1; x_2]$. Even just a reference, technique, or theorem to look up would be appreciated. A more thorough treatment is welcome too of course.

Comment: You just found the factorization.  Are you asking how this should be done in general?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe I only found the factorization of $x^TAx$ and not $x^TAx+c^Tx$ though. I'd like to know the latter and in general how to approach such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have something of the form
$$
f(x_1,x_2) = ax_1^2 + bx_1x_2 + cx_2^2 + dx_1 + ex_2
$$
We can write this as
\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= ax_1^2 + \frac b2 x_1x_2 + \frac b2 x_2x_1 + cx_2^2 + dx_1 + ex_2
\\ &= x^T\pmatrix{a & b/2\\b/2&c}x + \pmatrix{d&e} x
\end{align}
where $x = \pmatrix{x_1 & x_2}^T$

Comment: Thank you Omnonnomnom. Appreciate use of variables here. I'll pose the same question I did to user44197. Is there a source I might reference where you learned said technique above? I am building my reference lists as I learn LA. It is hard to know where certain things are located.

Comment: This should be something found in any LA textbook in the section on quadratic forms.  Usually, they don't include the linear term though.

Answer (score 1):

TYou are almost there!
what is left is $-x_1$ so $c = [-1,0]$

$$
A = \pmatrix{1& -1/2\\-1/2 & 2 }, ~\text{which you have, and }\\
C = \pmatrix{-1, 0}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am glad to award an answer. If you don't mind, can you also comment on a systematic way to approach these types of factorizations. I don't really understand it, I merely followed a pattern from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections

Comment: user44197, I feel badly not being able to award you both the answer. I gave you points though. Omnomnomnom was first on the scene clarifying the question and so I feel it fair to award the answer to Omnomnomnom. However, I really appreciate your answer and the speed with which you gave it. If I might ask, do you have a reference from which you learned the technique used here? I am learning LA and it helps to know decent references.